# how can i use HtmlAgilityPack to measure loading time of html content(include img , div tags and etc)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack, stopwatch

I'm going to measure loading time of website that it's don't develop by my own, i knew from somewhere i must use HtmlAgilityPack to measure html content loading time.
 Here is my code:

```
    Stopwatch stop_w = new Stopwatch(); 
    long time_elap = 0;
    string url = "http://www.varzesh3.com/";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
    foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
    {
        stop_w.Start();
        lbl1.Text += node.InnerHtml + "<br />";
        stop_w.Stop();
        time_elap += stop_w.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

time_elap will return loading time of html content.
Is it correct?

Comment: No. Put a stopwatch around `web.Load()`. There are better ways to do this btw, check out mini-profiler

Comment: I think it is impossible it returned 154445 ms for loading time!

Comment: Nope. Read your code, all you're doing is timing how long it takes to append the node inner text to your label text for every anchor in the page. You want to time how long it takes the whole page to load. So wrap the `web.Load(url)` call between `stop_w.Start()` and `stop_w.Stop()`.

Comment: OK i did it, is it accurate?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `HtmlAgilityPack` to do this.

Just use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx):

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

sw.Start();
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
     //do something
}
sw.Stop();

Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Note, i don't need to response time i need to whole loading time that it might take at least 5 second!

Comment: @Dash_Javad That IS the whole loading time.

Comment: But it takes less than 2 sec i think it isn't Reasonable.

Comment: ? What is the url you're testing this with? Why is that unreasonable?

Comment: It is a site just for test i can use www.google.com instead. i heard from some programmer that i must split all of site elements to it's component( like js, css , html ,flash,etc) and i must measure them loading time separately and i saw in some sites such http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ it's proof.